# Key combinations not working properly in Minecraft

Tags: keyboard, games, minecraft

I am running Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS (an Ubuntu based distro) and when playing Minecraft, I run into an issue whenever I combine two or more keys at the same time.

Just to clear things up: I've experienced the **exact** same problem in Ubuntu, and Pop OS is really similar to it. I've done lots of research on YouTube, and here too. I saw post from someone with the same problem (in Ask Ubuntu), it was published a year ago, however, it is unanswered until today, so I thought it would be better to write this.

I am running the program natively, the game, my drivers and system are up to date. And there are no shortcuts associated with the keys I use when playing the game.

I was used to simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (both keys at the same time) to run, and that worked well on Windows 10, with the same keyboard I am using now. Basically, pressing both keys will result in none of them being registered, which is a major change to the gameplay and the experience.

I've tried updating drivers & all of that, nothing worked. I would be happy if someone could helping me solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind linking to the question on AskUbuntu?

Comment: Greetings, AdminBee.
Here is the link to the post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161962/combinations-of-keys-in-minecraft-do-not-work-reliably.

Sadly, when I posted it, the fact I use Pop!_OS made my question invalid, and they asked me to remove it.